# Change text to a form with a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of comments on a model and I want the user who submitted the comments to be able to edit the comments without having to navigate away from the display page.  So given the picture below that displays the comments:

[image]

I want the user to be able to click the edit button (pencil on the right side) and the comment becomes editable.

Im not sure how to go about this, but I was thinking I could make the edit button a remote: true link that re-renders the partial of the commment as the edit comment partial instead.  And then the submit would just re-render it again (via Ajax) back to the original partial.  Is this the right approach or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at X-editable https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/, it does the same thing as your requirement.

Comment: This got me looking in the right areas and what to search for alternative methods as well.  Thank you